# Multiple asyncio loops

Tags: python, concurrency, operating-system, python-asyncio

I am implementing a service in a multi-service python application. This service will wait for requests to be pushed in a redis queue and resolve them whenever one is available.

```
async def foo():
    while True:
        _, request = await self.request_que.brpop(self.name)
        # processing request ...
```

And I'm adding this `foo()` function to an asyncio event loop:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(self.handle(), loop=loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

The main question is, is it ok to do this on several(say 3 or 4) different services, that results in running several asyncio loops simultaneously? Will it harm OS?

Comment: That is possible but in most cases not needed. Every event loop has to run in its own thread.

Comment: So in case I run them in different threads, it's ok?

Comment: @P.Alipoor as long as your event loop run in different threads they wouldn't disrupt each other. Note, however, that these loops will be independent: for example, task created for one loop can't be awaited by other loop, etc.

Comment: Thanks, But my main answer was about the overload on the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: yes. It is fine. I previously implemented a service which runs on one asyncio loop and spawns additional processes which run on their own loop (within the same machine).